# How to show full xAxis title in dimple.js?

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

This is my dimple line chart (powered by d3):
but the xAxis ltitle overlap with xAxis  title
like the image [image]

how to show the full xAxis title and not to overlap with the xAxis  text?

Then I have this code in a php file:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400),
data = [
    { "Value" : 4, "timestamp" : 09:33:00},
    { "Value" : 10, "timestamp" : 09:33:05},
    { "Value" : 2, "timestamp" : 09:33:50},
    { "Value" : 1, "timestamp" : 09:34:00},
    { "Value" : 5, "timestamp" : 09:34:20},
    { "Value" : 6, "timestamp" : 09:35:00}
];


// Draw a standard chart using the aggregated data

var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.setBounds(60, 30, 700, 300);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "timestamp");
 x.title = "per 5 seconds";
 x.addOrderRule("Year");
var y = chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Value");
var s = chart.addSeries(["Volume", "timestamp"], dimple.plot.bubble);

// Add a thick line with markers
  var lines = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
  lines.lineWeight = 5;
  lines.lineMarkers = true;
  chart.draw();
  x.shapes.selectAll("text").attr("transform",
function (d) {
  return d3.select(this).attr("transform") + " rotate(45)";
});
```

Could anybody help me with this? Is it possible to do it in a way I am trying? 
It would be great if you could point me to some worked out examples or tutorials

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/staUc.jpg):

Comment: Why not put in in a JSON object and use ajax to post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `rotate(45)`to set custom coordinates. Thankfully, this is very easy to do by using `rotate(45,0,0)` where you set 0,0 according to your needs. Especially the second parameter moves your labels up and down.

here's a working pen to try it out. Just try to use `rotate(45,-10,0)` or `rotate(45,10,0)` to see what happens:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEbKRN?editors=1111

(i felt free to add `""` to your dates in the array to make things work)

and here are the examples of dimple you perhaps searched for: 
http://dimplejs.org/examples_index.html

disclaimer: I never used dimple before, just d3. There might be a better "dimple" way, but though you are changing the rotation of your labels via D3 nontheless, this might be the best way for you here.

**edit**:

You can get direct access to the x- and y-position of the title label via the following function after drawing the chart:

```
x.titleShape.attr("y",
    function (d) {
      return "420"; //you may want to calculate this dynamically.
    });
```

for codepen seems down at the moment, here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kue2arnh/3/

Comment: from your codepen, the xAxis title "per 5 second " will overlap the xAxis text , How to move the title to bottom of the xAxis text ?

Comment: but i try if the dataset only have two records, the x position still can show full x value , like http://jsfiddle.net/andrewarnier/m9x6m3pa/1/